# Get Description of attribute based on value of another attribute

Tags: c#, reflection, attributes

Please consider this Code:

```
[ShowFieldByRole(User1 = false, User2 = false, User3 = true)]
[FieldName(Name = "Desciption1")]
public string G_Sum{set; get;}

[ShowFieldByRole(User1 = false, User2 = false, User3 = false)]
[FieldName(Name = "Desciption2")]
public string G_Sum2{set; get;}

[ShowFieldByRole(User1 = false, User2 = false, User3 = true)]
[FieldName(Name = "Desciption3")]
public string G_Sum3{set; get;}
```

I create two custom attribute class and now I want get all description(the value of 
`Name` property of `FieldName` attribute) of properties that attribute `User3=true` with reflection.

for example according to above code I want to get `Description2,Descriptio3` because their `User3` equal to `true`

How I can do this?

thanks

---

**Edit 1)**

I wrote this code and it returns `Description2,Descriptio3`:

```
var My = typeof(ClassWithAttr).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public)
                          .Where(p => p.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(FieldName), true)
                          .Where(ca => ((ShowFieldByRole)ca).User3 == true)
                          .Any()).Select(p=>p.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(FieldName),true).Cast<FieldName>().FirstOrDefault().Name);
```

Now I want to return `[PropertyName , Name]` When I write the code this way:

```
    var My = typeof(ClassWithAttr).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public)
                          .Where(p => p.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(FieldName), true)
                          .Where(ca => ((ShowFieldByRole)ca).User3 == true)
                          .Any()).ToDictionary(f => f.Name, h=>h.GetValue(null).ToString());
```

but I got this error:

> Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEqualityComparer' because it is not a delegate type

Where is the problem?

Comment: Well, what would you normally do to find one value based on another? Think of the attributes as if they were properties of `PropertyInfo` (just a bit harder to use).

Comment: I edit my code and question please see again.

Comment: Dear @JonSkeet I reach to first result .please see my Edit 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your last example both `f` and `h` are `PropertyInfo`

The correct code for your case is

```
var dictionay = (from propertyInfo in typeof (ClassWithAttr).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public)
                 where propertyInfo.GetCustomAttributes(typeof (ShowFieldByRoleAttribute), true).Cast<ShowFieldByRoleAttribute>().Any(a => a.User3)
                 from FieldNameAttribute fieldName in propertyInfo.GetCustomAttributes(typeof (FieldNameAttribute), true)
                 select new { PropertyName = propertyInfo.Name, FiledName = fieldName.Name })
    .ToDictionary(x => x.PropertyName, x => x.FiledName);
```

**UPD** using method chains

```
var dictionay = typeof (ClassWithAttr).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public)
    .Where(p => p.GetCustomAttributes(typeof (ShowFieldByRoleAttribute), true).Cast<ShowFieldByRoleAttribute>().Any(a => a.User3))
    .SelectMany(p => p.GetCustomAttributes(typeof (FieldNameAttribute), true).Cast<FieldNameAttribute>(),
                (p, a) => new { PropertyName = p.Name, FiledName = a.Name })
    .ToDictionary(a => a.PropertyName, a => a.FiledName);
```

Comment: thanks it works.But can you write this with lamda expression too